# Key data not storing to iCloud with NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore.defaultStore

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, icloud

So I have a simple goal, just to get this working.  So theoretically if you ruined this.

1. Triggered save players
2. waited a bit
3. Deleted the app
4. Rebuilt (downloaded)
5. Triggered restore then the word "MEDO" would print to the console

But instead it is null, making me pretty sure that it is not saving to iC cloud some reason.  I followed [this](http://www.ryanwright.me/cookbook/ios/obj-c/application-settings/icloud) tutorial. Perhaps it is too outdated to work?

```
func c_restoreCharecters()
    {
        let icloud = NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore.defaultStore()
        println(icloud.objectForKey("username"))
    }

    func c_savePlayers()
    {
        let icloud = NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore.defaultStore()
        icloud.setObject("MEDO", forKey: "username")
        println(icloud.synchronize())
    }
```

Obviously I am going to use this concept for something completely different in the future, but I have to get the basics down first!

Some other stuff:
iCloud set up in my settings:
[image]
My Entitlements file: 
[image]

Comment: Data doesn't even show up in my I cloud data browser