# Is my app's entitlement file looking correct? What is its purpose?

Tags: xcode, swift, sprite-kit, icloud, game-center

I am having a really hard time getting iCloud working as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33590375/key-data-not-storing-to-icloud-with-nsubiquitouskeyvaluestore-defaultstore) (currently unsolved) topic.  However this topic isn't about that, it is about my entitlements file.  I was just wondering if it was weird that the file itself says nothing about the other capabilities of my app such as iAP's or GameCenter etc.  Is it all configured properly or did my make it wrong/need to add new things to it?

Here is a picture of it.  As you can see their are only entries for iCloud.
[image: As you can see]

Am I missing some entries that should be their?  What is the purpose of this file when their is already those switches in the "capabilities" section of the app?